# Inserting Checked value of checkbox in gridview in db not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

[image]

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here because I tried every possible solution on the internet for a month and I still didn't get it to work. 
All I am trying to do is inserting the checked checkboxes into a table called 
PrescTest (idPrescTest int primary key identity, Test nvarchar(50), idPresc int)

but I am getting this error message: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'idPresc', table 'Project.dbo.PrescTest'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Here is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((row.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into PrescTest (Test) values (@Test)", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Test", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = row.Cells[2].Text;

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                Response.Redirect("PrescForm.aspx");

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What isn't clear about that error message? The column idPresc does not allow NULL and it is NOT in your insert statement. Slight detour....you should be wrapping your connection and command objects in a USING statement. The way this is coded you are going to kill your connection pool.

Comment: At least they've parametrised the statement though @SeanLange. A *refreshing* change.

Comment: You are totally right but I need to insert this checked data before inserting the idPresc in the primary table

Comment: I need to fill PrescTest table before filling Prescription table, is there any way to fix that ?

Comment: If that columns requires a value you MUST provide a value. That is the whole point of referential integrity. Not to kindly ask for a value if it is convenient. It will start kicking and screaming that you didn't give it a value because it demands one. The only way around that would be to make that column allow NULL which would leave you in the situation of allowing orphaned data. Perhaps you need to look at the process.

Comment: Yes i see my problem is the primary key doesnt exist to use it as a foreign key.

Comment: But is there a way to handle it without changing how I am processing things?

Comment: The only way to do without changing your process would be to allow that column to be NULL. You are trying to insert child data before the parent exists. That logically doesn't make sense because you have child data with no parent.

Comment: I did and it worked. but can I insert the foreign key after that ? Because i cant leave it always NULL

Comment: No you cant, because if there is always a change there are rows left with no id and that would fail the creation of the foreign key. Your logic is simply put not a correct logic. You cannot insert children when there is no parent. The only way I see how to do this is to create a parent first

Comment: @GuidoG ann okay thank you!